# Reload data in tableview while scrolling with API

Tags: objective-c

how to reload the data in the table while scrolling?

If i have a url "http:.......&start=0&limit=50".

How to reload the data in table with incrementing the start and limit value with 50.

Can anyone find a solution for this?

Comment: I hope you want to integrate pagination!

Comment: how to add pagination ? I am not used this method.

Comment: check this blog http://uiroshan.github.io/2015/02/01/ios-uitableview-load-data-while-scrolling/

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to implement the load more functionality in the table view for this.In order to do so, you need to track the table view's index while it is scrolling once table reaches the last cell you can call the api with increased page number and add the new records to the array once you get the positive response from the api.
2. See the below code for more understanding.
3. Variable initialization

   ```
   @interface ExampleListVC (){
       BOOL hasNextPage,isLoadingNextPage;
       int currentPage;
       NSMutableArray *arrTableData;
   }
   @end
   ```
4. In viewDidLoad method

   ```
   arrTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   currentPage=-1;
   hasNextPage = YES;
   ```
5. In tableView numberOfRowsInSection method

   ```
   -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
     int count = (int)arrTableData.count;
     if (hasNextPage)
     {
        count++;
     }
     return count;
   }
   ```
6. In cellForRowAtIndexPath method

   ```
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
      UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
      if (indexPath.row<arrTableData.count)
      {
        //Load TableviewCell you intend to show
      }
      else
      {
         //Show loading cell
         cell = [self loadingCell:indexPath];
         if (!isLoadingNextPage)
         {
           [self fetchData];
         }
      }
      return  cell;
    }
   ```
7. Loading Cell Code

   ```
   -(UITableViewCell *) loadingCell :(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
      cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView =[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    activityIndicatorView.color = [UIColor blackColor];
    activityIndicatorView.center = CGPointMake(self.tblView.center.x, cell.center.y);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:activityIndicatorView];
    [activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    return cell;
   }
   ```
8. Api call implementation

   ```
   -(void)fetchData
   {
      isLoadingNextPage = YES;
      if (currentPage==-1)
         currentPage=0;
      //API Call
      {
    DLog(@"API Call Response = %@",response);
    isLoadingNextPage = NO;
    if (response == nil)
    {
        hasNextPage=NO;
        return;
    }

    if (success)
    {
        if (hasNextPage)
        {
            currentPage++;
        }
        [arrTableData addObjectsFromArray:response];
    }
    else
    {
        hasNextPage=NO;
    }
    //Reload tableview
   }];
   }
   ```

**Alternative solution for this is**
Use the SVPullToRefresh library in integrate infinite scrolling of it.
https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(self.comptabl.contentOffset.y >= (self.comptabl.contentSize.height - self.comptabl.bounds.size.height))
    {
        if(isPageRefreshing==NO){
            isPageRefreshing=YES;
            [appDelegate showIndicator:nil view1:self.view];
            start=start+50;

            [self makeRequest:start];
            [self.comptabl reloadData];
            NSLog(@"called %d",start);
        }



    }
}
```

I am using this method but at all time the value is increment with 50 ..how can i set limit to the value